# Change the maximum allowed length of string values ingested through the Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, data-ingestion

We are using the google-analytics-data module in Azure Databricks to ingest data from GA4. However, one field which has string values with a length of more than 100 characters gets cut off by the API. How can we adjust this so that these long string values are ingested completely in stead of partially?

So far I haven't come across a setting which allow you to ingest string values with a length longer than 100 characters.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code